# BoldReport unable to load RDL reports from SSRS Report Server

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, syncfusion

I'm using syncfusion bold reports in my angular project and creating RDL reports using SQL Server 2017. What I'm trying to do is to view SSRS report on BoldReport viewer by following this [link](https://help.boldreports.com/angular/report-viewer/ssrs-report/). But unfortunately facing some kind of error and the report is not viewing on Client Side.

Here is the error:

[image]

**Detail**

> Provide the valid report server information (ReportServerURL, ReportServerCredential, ReportPath) to retrieve the report stream from server.Could not connect with the Report Server Service. at Syncfusion.Report.Core.Intenal.Server.SqlReportingServer2017.GetReportDefinition(String& exception) at BoldReports.Intenal.Server.ServerReportProcessor.GetReportDefinition(String& exception) at BoldReports.RDL.Data.ReportModel.ProcessServerReport()

By understanding above error I was thinking there is some Credential, ServerURL issue. But changing these parameters in code doesn't seem to resolve this error.

**Code**

```
    public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
    {
        //Add SSRS Report Server and data source credentials
        reportOption.ReportModel.ReportServerCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sa", "123");

        reportOption.ReportModel.DataSourceCredentials.Add(new BoldReports.Web.DataSourceCredentials("ReportServer", "sa", "123"));
    }
```

Report Server Configuration Manager:

[image]

[image]

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public serviceUrl: string;
  public serverUrl: string;
  public reportPath: string;

  constructor() {
    this.serviceUrl = 'https://localhost:44304/api/ReportViewer';
    this.serverUrl = 'https://desktop-dfe3e8t/ReportServer';
    this.reportPath = '/PurchaseRequests';
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<bold-reportviewer id="reportViewer_Control" [reportServiceUrl]="serviceUrl" [processingMode]="Remote" [reportServerUrl]="serverUrl" [reportPath]="reportPath">
</bold-reportviewer>
```

If I hit on browser with serverUrl it shows me my SSRS report

[image]

[image]

But when I run my angular app and my viewer is load it shows me above error

[image]

Kindly guide me what I'm doing wrong in my above code or steps to view my Bold Report in angular.

Comment: Hi Ahsan, I'm facing the same issue, did you find the solution? if yes, could you please share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the ASP.NET Core service for report viewer then you should use Web portal URL for reportserverurl instead of using Report Service URL for SSRS.  Also, ensure you are enabled the necessary [permissions](https://help.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting-tools/faq/ssrs-enable-permission/) for the user to get the reports from SSRS for report processing.

Comment: I'm already using web portal url kindly see my above code in this.serverurl on the other hand I'm using web api url in this.serviceurl.

Comment: Even setting up proper permissions and using both report sever url and report service url I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The Syncfusion directions here (https://help.boldreports.com/javascript/report-viewer/ssrs-report/) say to use the Web Service URL, but I got it to work using the Web Portal URL

Answer (score 0):

With the same setting, it worked fine for me only my connecting to SSRS 2019